# Problems with shuffling array of HTML links

Tags: javascript, arrays, shuffle

I'm running a site where the user's only way of navigating the subdirectories is via random pages (akin to Wikipedia's Random Page feature). I already implemented a code to call up random pages and it works fine, but I want to minimize the chance of the same page being called up again after the onclick execution.

I stumbled over the Fisher-Yates-Knuth shuffle while researching a better method and tried to implement it into my script:

```
function Next() {
   var links = [];
   links[0] = "/arch/g1";
   links[1] = "/arch/g2";
   links[2] = "/arch/g3";
   links[3] = "/arch/g4";

   var m = links.length, t, i;
   while (m) {
      i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);
      t = links[m];
      links[m] = links[i];
      links[i] = t;
   }
   window.location = links[m]
}
```

The script basically works, but it still results in calling up the same page twice or even three times in a row. I'm still pretty new at JS, so it'd be great if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Set a cookie with visited indicii and skip them that session

Comment: This is the nature of (pseudo)randomness, given numbers 1 through 3, if I chose them truly at random, 3 may come up 1 million times in a row (even though the probability of that happening is very low).  It seems like your function is working correctly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eeach call on Next() function is shuffle array of links and get one index from array. You have 4 different links, on calling this function 3 times you have good chance to get same page.

Try this:

```
var links = ["/arch/g1","/arch/g2","/arch/g3","/arch/g4"];

function shuffle(links) {
    var m = links.length, t, i;
    while (m) {
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);
    t = links[m];
    links[m] = links[i];
    links[i] = t;
    }
}

function Next(){
    if(links.length === 0){
        links = ["/arch/g1","/arch/g2","/arch/g3","/arch/g4"];
        shuffle(links);
    }

    var nextUrl = links[links.length - 1];
    links.splice(links.length - 1, 1);
    window.location = nextUrl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried it out, but when I call up the function via onclick on the corresponding page, the following happens: it always opens up the new page in the same window (which is what I'm aiming for), but it's always g4, no matter if I call the function on g1, g2 or g3. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: I tinkered around with it a bit and now it seems to work fine. Thanks!